# Distribution of number of points in a region of blue noise

Tags: geometric-probability, noise

Let $X$ be a spatial blue noise point process in the plane where points are at least distance $d$ apart for $d > 0$.

For a closed region in the plane $B$, let $N(B)$ count the number of points in $B$.

What is the distribution of $N(B)$?

My guess is that $N(B)$ could be a truncation of a Poisson distribution, from my intuition that [blue noise](https://blog.demofox.org/2017/10/20/generating-blue-noise-sample-points-with-mitchells-best-candidate-algorithm/) is like [white noise](https://blog.demofox.org/2017/10/20/generating-blue-noise-sample-points-with-mitchells-best-candidate-algorithm/) but with a minimum distance between points. See Baddeley, *Spatial point processes and their applications* for white noise, as in a spatial Poisson process.

*Remark*: This question is my attempt to [resolve an earlier question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4667270) from a different direction.

**References**

Baddeley, Adrian, *Spatial point processes and their applications*, Weil, Wolfgang (ed.), Stochastic geometry. Lectures given at the C.I.M.E. summer school held in Martina Franca, Italy, September 13–18, 2004. With additional contributions by D. Hug, V. Capasso, E. Villa. Berlin: Springer (ISBN 3-540-38174-0/pbk). Lecture Notes in Mathematics 1892, 1-75 (2007). [ZBL1127.62086](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1127.62086).